# Retrieving multiple Set-Cookie headers in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, cookies, request

So I am using UnityWebRequest to call server that return 3 Set-Cookie headers. When calling method GetResponseHeaders (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetResponseHeaders.html) I can only see the first one, second and third are missing.

```
 set-cookie: wp_woocommerce_session_some bla; expires=Thu, 04-Oct-2018 
 08:29:58 GMT; Max-Age=166371; path=/
set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_some more bla; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; path=/
```

Is that known unity issue, anyone found a way around it? This topic here thought might be helpful - [Retrieving multiple "Set-Cookie" headers from a HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600022/retrieving-multiple-set-cookie-headers-from-a-httpwebresponse). Unfortunately I am unable to implement Cookie Container in unity3d. 
Any help would be appreciated.